# How to fix Restler + Explorer + Nginx (gives 404)

Tags: nginx, explorer, restler

I have RESTler and the explorer working with Apache but it won't work with Nginx.

The API works fine (server.com/api/class works fine) but http://server.com/api/explorer/index.html gives an Nginx 404.

Anyone out there with RESTler + nginx + explorer working that wants to share his nginx configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

I have explorer working with nginx, my config:

```
root         /var/www/test/;

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/socket.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /api {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
    }
}
```

fastcgi_param

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
...
```